# I want to do process.start one app and wait until it is done before going on to another app in VB 2022. How do I do it. I have a snippet of code

Tags: process.start

I'm working on a movie launcher (Movie Magic) launching a movie on a click to a listbox holding the path to the `.mp4`. I want it to launch a random cartoon and blank out the second screen. How do I get it to wait after the first process.start until the cartoon finishes before launching the movie? Below is the snippet that I am trying to use.

```
'This line works to launch the random cartoon. Just won't wait. :-)
 Process.Start(GetRandomCartoon)

'This line launches the movie fine. It is directed to the left screen. Been using it for years.
 Process.Start(strShortcut & LbxLaunch.Items.Item(intSelect))

'This line blanks the right screen so only the left screen is lit.
 Process.Start("K:\QDrive\Visual Studio 2022\Projects 65\Shades R\bin\Release\Shades R.exe")

'This one closes the function... :-)
 Close()
```

Comment: What programming language are you using?